# ApiError: Error during request while uploading file from Firebase Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I'm parsing some emails forwarded from MailGun, while trying to store the attachment I'm getting the error below:

```
ApiError: Error during request.
        at Object.parseHttpRespBody (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/src/util.js:193:32)
        at Object.handleResp (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/src/util.js:137:18)
        at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/src/util.js:496:12
        at Request.onResponse [as _callback] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/retry-request/index.js:195:7)
        at Request.self.callback (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
        at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
        at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
        at Request.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/request/request.js:1163:10)
        at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
        at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
```

**Here's the initialization**

```
// Initializes the database and storage
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const db = admin.firestore();
const storage = admin.storage();
const bucket = storage.bucket('gs://my-bucket-address');
```

**I'm grabbing the file via busboy**

```
busboy.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
    // Note that os.tmpdir() is an in-memory file system
    const filepath = path.join(tmpdir, filename)
    uploads[fieldname] = filepath;
    file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath));
});
```

**Here's where it fails**

```
busboy.on('finish', () => {
    const body_text = formData['body-plain'];
    const body_data = JSON.parse(body_text);
    const sender = body_data.sender;

    for (const name in uploads) {
        const file = uploads[name];

        const metadata = { contentType: 'image/jpeg'};
        const random_id = uuid4();
        const destination = `images/${sender}/${random_id}.jpg`;

        bucket.upload(filepath, { destination: destination, metadata: metadata });
        fs.unlinkSync(file);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to use GCS and not functions.storage.bucket. I was also having the same issue with GCS but that was because I was initializing GCS before initializing the the app with `initializeApp`. This was causing GCS not being properly authenticated. I just which the API error was a bit more helpful.

EDIT: Added code for reference

```
// Import the modules
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

// Initialize Admin FIRST
admin.initializeApp();

// Import GSC now
const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')();

// Than you can access the bucket
const bucket = gcs.bucket('your-bucket.appspot.com');
```

You can find your bucket url [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-buckets)

Comment: Can you post the final code that worked as a reference?

Comment: @Shaun Code added, sorry for the late reply.